# Can anyone recommend the most interesting 2 or 3 day cycle in Vietnam?

Tags: southeast-asia, bicycles, vietnam

If I wanted to go on a supported cycle in Vietnam for 2 or 3 days, where would be a good place to start/end?  It would be good to see the countryside, some of the more rural areas, be off the main roads and somewhere relatively flat.

Comment: Hi WW. I just wanted to let you know that Stack Exchange does not generally welcome recommendation questions or any kind of subjective question. The Travel Stack Exchange site however will accept some very specific such questions only so please add as many details as possible. Vietnam is a large area of land and there will be varying views as to what is "most interesting".

Comment: This may or may not interest you but [*Top Gear* did a special episode on motorcycling across Vietnam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gear:_Vietnam_Special). While not possible to do same on bicycle, it should give you an idea of what the countryside is like.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about 'supported trips' but I did many day trips by bike in Vietnam.
One I really enjoyed was around [Ninh Binh](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ninh_Binh) in North Vietnam, two and a half hours by bus south of Hanoi.

We based ourselves in Ninh Binh and rented bikes to explore the surrounding sites:

- Tam Coc, beautiful limestone cliffs surrounded by rice paddies.
- Trang An Grottoes
- Cuc Phuong National Park
- Some nice temples a little further south which I can't recall the name of.

The area is flat and rural and just cycling around in the countryside was a lot of fun.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/vietnam/activities/mountain-biking?sort_dir=desc&sort_order=popular) on [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/vietnam) provides a cycling specialty group in [VietNam](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/vm.html) (one of my favorite places). It might be worth calling or emailing them to see/hear their recommendations. It used to be rather difficult to travel freely in-country. Peter's method of basing yourself in one place seems quite practical.

If you are going up north, think about going out to [HaLong Bay](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/vietnam/northeast-vietnam/halong-bay). It's amazing. If you go out on a boat tour, don't go on a large boat. too impersonal and staged.

Good journey.

[image: Halong Bay]